# how to burn cd using php scripts or Any Api?

Tags: php, dvd-burning, cd-burning

I want to enable windows cd burn using php script or any api key,or any programable language script.how it is possible to do that with php or any programable language script?

Please Suggest?

Comment: makes so little sense to consider php for this

Answer (score 2):

PHPs main function is preparing and building webpages to display in a clients browser.

I don't think there is any functionality to access the disk drive with PHP alone nor do I think it would be a good idea.

The only way I can think it would work is by running tools installed on the OS through php's exec() function

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

I Have not used these tools but that's what I found when googling commandline CD ripping and burning.

> https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-ripping-and-encoding-audio-files/

FYI, php runs serverside only so using the linux tools would only work on the hosting machine.

With all the opensource disc management tools out there I cant work out why you would want to build one in php